# Group query to get specific order

Tags: development, rest, query

I use this query to populate my gallery:

```
  var queryGallery = "$select=Title,Description,Enlace,EncodedAbsUrl,Categoria/Title&$expand=Categoria/Title";


$.ajax({
url: url + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listname + "')/items?$top=1000&" + queryGallery, 
//url: url + "/_api/web/lists/getbycategory('Office'),

method: "GET",
headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
success: function (data) {
    completeGalleryContent(data, target, eng);
},
error: function (data) {
    failureGalleryContent(data, target);
}
});
}
```

The problem is that I don´t know why first take one image of each category and after that get all images of one categorie, for example
I have this categories

Services, Home, Office

In my first row of images I get:

```
firstimageServices
firstimageHome
firstimageOffice
secondimageOffice
thirdimageOffice
etc...
```

But I want to group all by categorie, so it will be:

```
firstimageServices
secondimageServices
thirdimageServices
fourimageServices
etc...
firstimageHome
secondimageHome
thirdimageHome
fourimageHome
etc...
firstimageOffice
secondimageOffice
thirdimageOffice
fourimageOffice
etc..
```

How can I do in my query to group it? Regards!

Note: I look something of interest in these link [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc751316.aspx) but how can I apply it in my query to sort by "Categoria"

Comment: Add `$orderby=Categoria,Title asc` to queryGallery?

Comment: It don´t works, I add it like`var queryGallery = "$select=Title,Description,Enlace,EncodedAbsUrl,Categoria/Title&$expand=Categoria/Title$orderby=Categoria,Title asc";` but It don´t pass to data, I review my question and I need to sort by Title so I do that: "$select=Title,Description,Enlace,EncodedAbsUrl,Categoria/Title&$expand=Categoria/Title$orderby=Title asc";` but don´t works too@EricAlexander

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a '&$', not just '$' before the orderby clause, like this:

```
"$select=Title,Description,Enlace,EncodedAbsUrl,Categoria/Title&$expand=Categori‌​a/Title&$orderby=Categoria,Title asc";
```

Comment: Yes it works, you´re boss!!!!!!! but I only need to orderby Title so my answer is: `"$select=Title,Description,Enlace,EncodedAbsUrl,Categoria/Title&$expand=Categori‌​a/Title&$orderby=Title asc";`